# Embedding web content in the Analyzer

Tags: gooddata

does the GoodData platform allow to embed web content in the Analyzer? For example, would it be possible to play youtube videos on a dashboard? In case it is possible, how can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Embedding web content in a dashboard is currently possible in the Pixel Perfect UI only ([Embed Web Content](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/expand-your-gooddata-platform/gooddata-integration-into-your-application/embed-gooddata-elements-into-your-applications/embed-dashboards-and-reports/embedded-dashboard-and-report-api-events-and-methods/embedded-dashboard-events)). You can, however, configure drilling to a URL address in your KPI dashboard so users are redirected to a website when clicking on a measure. More information here: [Drill to URL from KPI Dashboards](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/dashboards-and-insights/kpi-dashboards/drilling-in-kpi-dashboards/drill-to-url-from-kpi-dashboards).
Lastly, It is also possible to embed your insights or dashboards into your own web application so you could show them alongside the intended web content.